Stolen BTC, in 2012
Back in 2012 I purchased bitcoin from a company called " Bitcoin Nordic "
Who where acquired by " Coinify "in 2014.
But the funds where transferred. My wallet is zero.
I have the original email, transactions and addresses.
Can it be retrieved,
I know it's a long shot, ?

What did Coinify say when you reached out to them?

They where ok, looked into it to be fair,

Said Bitcoin Nordic was solely an exchange platform, he also search my wallet address on the blockchain and gave n

Me the results showing the bitcoin was sent to another address
